# How to rename path name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have `.dcm` files in a path like below `(old_path)`;

```
old_path: Mass-Test_P_00016_LEFT_MLO_1/10-04-2016-DDSM-15563/1-cropped images-77287/000000.dcm
```

I have to rename the path like below `(good_path)`;

```
good_path: Mass-Test_P_00016_LEFT_MLO_1/15563/77287/000000.dcm
```

Note that I keep only the last 5 digits in the sub-folders as shown above.

Please anyone show me how this must be done?
This is my attempt...

```
os.chdir(path to data)
os.listdir()
>> ['Mass-Test_P_00016_LEFT_MLO_1', 'Mass-Test_P_00016_LEFT_MLO']

temp = os.walk('Mass-Test_P_00016_LEFT_MLO_1', topdown=False)
for root, dirs, files in temp:
    for name in files:
        old_path = os.path.join(root, name)
        print("old_path: ", old_path)
        first = old_path.split('/')[1][-5:]
        second = old_path.split('/')[2][-5:]
        #print(first, second)
        good_path = os.path.join(old_path.split('/')[0], first, second, old_path.split('/')[3])
        print("good_path: ", good_path)
        os.rename(old_path, good_path)
```

I was able to set the `good_path` as I want. But it is not overwriting the `subfolders` names.

Comment: Suggest you use `os.path.split()` to split paths (instead of e.g. `old_path.split('/')`).

Comment: What happens when you run your code? What do you want it to do differently?

Comment: Tip: set the result of `old_path.split('/')` to a variable so you don't have to keep calling it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice. I get the following error. But there is no issue with the file location. **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Mass-Test_P_00016_LEFT_MLO_1/10-04-2016-DDSM-15563/1-cropped images-77287/000000.dcm' -> 'Mass-Test_P_00016_LEFT_MLO_1/15563/77287/000000.dcm'**

Comment: The error says the file you are trying to rename doesn't exist. Likely the problem is because you are using a relative path. So the file you **think** you are renaming isn't the actual file that the program is **actually** renaming.

Comment: Are you trying to rename multiple folders along the path with one call to rename()??

Comment: yes @ Rashid 'Lee' Ibrahim. Is that possible in python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to rename each node of your path from the root (the left most folder of `old_path`) to the leaf (your `.dcm` file). You might be interested in using `os.renames` instead of `os.rename`